# Optimize scroll speed for Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, scroll, internet-explorer-11

I currently have an agenda-like application where the first column is absolute horizontal and the first row absolute vertical. I am achieving this by catching the scroll effect and change the left or top property of the CSS class it's attached to. ( these classes can be up to 700 items ( 2 years each day )).

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.Planning tr > td:first-child').css("left", "" + $(this).scrollLeft() + "px");
    $('.Planning thead > tr:first-child').css("top", $(this).scrollTop()+50 + "px");                 
});
```

This works as expected in all browsers (I tested in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer)

But on Internet Explorer, it's very slow.
The scroll only shows after you stopped scrolling, whereas in Chrome and Firefox it looks like the top row is fixed, which looks better and more user friendly.

Is there any way to boost this? Or any libraries who are optimized for Internet Explorer so I can avoid this "slow" behaviour in IE?

https://jsfiddle.net/7mfcrLh5/12/ For a jsfiddle example ( this works great in chrome but not in internet explorer )

Answer (score 0):

You could try to [throttle](http://sampsonblog.com/749/simple-throttle-function) the functionality of the scroll function every 100ms or 200ms which is still pretty fast each second.

```
var planningCol = $('.Planning tr > td:first-child'),
    planningHead = $('.Planning thead > tr:first-child');

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var self = this;

    throttle(function(){
        planningCol.css({ left: $(self).scrollLeft() });
        planningHead.css('top', $(self).scrollTop() + 50 + 'px');
    }(), 200); // call your function directly upon return
});
```

Or you can use CSS on the body, detecting when a page is `scrolled` or `scrolling`. Then apply `.scrolling { pointer-events: none !important; }` which boosts the UI.

Also try to move the selections out of the scroll function if they are always the same.

```
var win = $(window),
    body = $(document.body),
    planning = $('.Planning'),
    planningCol = planning.find('tr > td').first(),
    planningHead = planning.find('thead > tr').first();

win.scroll(function(){
    // scrolled
    body.toggleClass('scrolled', !!win.scrollTop());

    // scrolling
    body.addClass('scrolling');
    planningCol.css({ left: win.scrollLeft() });
    planningHead.css({ top: win.scrollTop() });

    setTimeout(function(){
        body.removeClass('scrolling');
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the info, i tried like you suggested ( had to change the .first() for planningCol since there are multiple columns and for some reason planningcol.css({}) didn't work

it did manage to get it to work though this way:    planningHead.css("top", win.scrollTop() + 50 + "px");

though in the end the result on internet explorer is still very shaky :/ for example if i scroll from right to left the left column looks like it's not scrolling and stands in the middle of the screen until the scrolling has stopped and then set's itself right on the left

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Better to go ahead with my first paragraph, the throttle function. A [simple version](http://sampsonblog.com/749/simple-throttle-function) can be easily implemented. I'll see if I can edit my post.

Comment: Hi Tim,
I copied over the throttle function from in the link u copied but for some reason the code inside doesn't fire? ( i tried it with a console.log("test"); and i never see that log). I do however see a log if i log a console.log in the scroll event alone. I believe i'm still making a error in this throttle function.

Though if i understand this correct if i would implement a timer that runs every 200ms it would fix the 'lag' feeling on internet explorer

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. But please, try out jsfiddle to ease support for this issue and comment me the link.

Comment: Hi Tim,

https://jsfiddle.net/adkdhvck/2/

As you see, the throttle function never fires.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem. My bad! As the throttle function returns another function, we still have to call it. => `throttle(function(){/**/}(), 200);` I'll update once more and here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/0tfeg5aj/1/).

Comment: Hi Tim, yeah i'm sorry i didn't notice that myself. The function seems to work perfect in chrome and firefox but looks still the same in internet explorer. I guess it's just the javascript engine that can't render it properly?

Comment: Hi Tim, I made a fiddle to explain this more graphical: https://jsfiddle.net/7mfcrLh5/1/

As you see in chrome this will work perfect but in internet explorer it's kinda buggy

Comment: It's better when you simply use `.scrolled` state in this use-case.
But even if we do, all reflow inside your scrolling element in combination with fixed position or `positionTop` calls will cause problems on many devices. My [example](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/7mfcrLh5/7/) and some [other things](https://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios) to considder. Perhaps it's a good idea to lower expectations or ... take the topbar out of the scrolling element and prefer CSS state over JS.

Comment: Hi Tim, setting it fixed is something i can't do since then it's horizontal and vertical fixed ( where as in this use case it should one be fixed horizontal for 1 element and only vertical for the other )
https://jsfiddle.net/7mfcrLh5/12/ this fiddle maybe explains it more what i'm trying to achieve ( the red and green column/row), as you see there are items of the red column if you scroll down if the css is set to fixed, even if you scroll down you'll only be able to see the same first results every time.

Comment: Another [interesting article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/) about performance and reflow. Again, scrolling and offset calculations is not going to solve this issue.

Comment: So the answer to: "Is there any way to boost this? Or any libraries who are optimized for Internet Explorer so I can avoid this "slow" behaviour in IE?" is no?

Comment: Perhaps animate the CSS and use the `stop()` function to clear all overhead instead of throttle. [example](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/7mfcrLh5/20/). Problem is not javascript, it's reflow in combination with scrolling and offset, so no, you can't optimize this further. You have to rethink your design (HTML & CSS).