# How to prevent multiple fires for scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to prevent multi times scroll event, e.g. only one event in 250ms. For this I found the debounce function below in Internet. But I couldn't use it properly. What is wrong?

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

// my code..
$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {

  debounce(function() {
    // The stuff below doesn't work.
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 50) {
        $('.title').addClass('fixedPosition');
    } else {
        $('.title').removeClass('fixedPosition');
    }    
  }, 250);

});
```

Comment: I would add a mutex to the window object and release it in async every 250ms using the setTimeout function

Comment: Remove the wrapper function and just __call__ `debouce` as a handler argument of `on`.

Comment: Similar as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272182/optimize-scroll-speed-for-internet-explorer-11/39273882#39273882). You need to call the function that gets returned => `debounce(function(){/**/}(), 250);`

Comment: @Teemu I couldn't understand. Could you write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function `debounce` returns a function, you still need to call it:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
    debounce(function() {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > 50) {
            $('.title').addClass('fixedPosition');
        } else {
            $('.title').removeClass('fixedPosition');
        }    
    }()/*note the call here*/, 250);
});
```

This is not the same as wrapping your debounce logic in another function whereas the function `myLogic` will be called automatically:

```
function myLogic(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.title').toggleClass('fixedPosition', scrollTop > 50);
}

$(window).on('scroll', debounce(myLogic, 250));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I recorded function call times. The results: 1472906895811 1472906895835 1472906895855 1472906895874 1472906895898 1472906895922 1472906895944 1472906895966. The periyod seems to be less than 250ms. Why?

Comment: Perhaps you want throttle instead of debounce? See the [difference](http://jsfiddle.net/missinglink/19e2r2we/).

Comment: Yes, I want throttle. I think the code above behaves like throttle. Just the name is wrong?

Comment: You could try a [simpler version](http://sampsonblog.com/749/simple-throttle-function) of throttle and see if that works out for you. Not sure where you got that one from. Looks like this [one](https://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce). The thirth parameter `immediate` kinda gives it away and so it's a debounce function.