# Firefox 52 javascript scroll fire events lag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

Ever since FF 52 was introduced, I am having the same lagging issues when executing on scroll events, especially when using the mouse wheel - the same thing occurs on IE Edge as well, but it was considered a minority, now with the addition of FF some kind of a solution has to be found.

I have created a fiddle online that replicates the problem - the issue is visible on FF and IE edge, while it works smoothly across webkit browsers.

Here is the simple scroll function I am using:

```
$('.scrollable').on('scroll', function() {
  scrollY = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(this).find('td:first-child span').attr('style', 'transform:translateY(' + -scrollY + 'px)');
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nfmLa7mn/3/

If you scroll with the mouse wheel the issue is more visible. It's a small lag but it's there. In more complex layouts the issue is more pronounced.

Am I the only one bothered by this? I haven't seen any other similar topics online. Is there any way I am not aware of that can fire scroll events in a better way? Or is there any other way around this issue?

Comment: You should always [throttle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306738/how-to-prevent-multiple-fires-for-scroll-event/39306863#39306863) or [debounce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272182/optimize-scroll-speed-for-internet-explorer-11/39273882#39273882) this kind of events.

Comment: @TimVermaelen throttling or debouncing the scroll of a table? Really bad UX...

Comment: Yes, I'm not looking at what it is you're scrolling ... a table, the whole page ... it doesn't matter. I'm talking about the event rapidly firing and calculating your logic 100 times a second ...

Comment: @TimVermaelen Looks like I had misinterpreted how throttling works. The lag is now induced instead of just occurring, but it probably is a good way to go.

Comment: It should open up some more memory for the slower devices like phones and so on. Speaking of memory, it's not laggy at all on my end. Tested in Chrome, FF, IE. And Chrome uses the V8 engine to optimize performance. So it does make sense on your end if another process is slowing it down.

Comment: @TimVermaelen I am on a fast desktop, win10, 4790k, 32gb ram, nvidia 1070. The performance lag is noticeable only on FF (ever since v 52) and IE edge - it used to happen only on Edge but FF since v52 seem to ahve changed something to its engine so that the scroll events fire differently. Feels like it auto-manages the intervals where scroll events fire.

Comment: Hmm strange, I'm still on 47 ... let's have a test ... | seems fine on 53 aswell...

Comment: Current at v53 and I can still see the lag. Please use your mouse wheel instead of using the scrollbar and notice that right before the scrolling ends the borders don't align completely.

Comment: I honestly don't see what you mean. And I know how to scroll with my über l33t gaming mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is due to the fact that Firefox handles scroll asynchronously.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects

> Often scrolling effects are implemented by listening for the scroll event and then updating elements on the page in some way (usually the CSS position or transform property.) [...]
>
> These effects work well in browsers where the scrolling is done synchronously on the browser's main thread. However, most browsers now support some sort of asynchronous scrolling in order to provide a consistent 60 frames per second experience to the user. In the asynchronous scrolling model, the visual scroll position is updated in the compositor thread and is visible to the user before the scroll event is updated in the DOM and fired on the main thread. This means that the effects implemented will lag a little bit behind what the user sees the scroll position to be. This can cause the effect to be laggy, janky, or jittery — in short, something we want to avoid.